# "Make" meaning "force to do something"

Tags: syntax, licensing

As it is well known, among other meanings "make" means *force someone to do something* and searching on Google shows that the sentence "The boss made me work an extra day" is grammatical (68,500 hits). Nevertheless, the phrase "people were made to wait" is grammatical (907,000 hits), too.

Clearly, there is no parallelism between the two structures because in the first one "work" is  in the - so-called - bare infinitive form while in the second one the mentioned verb  is used as an infinitive ("to work").

Question is, is there a rule governing this matter?

Yet, if so, can such a rule be extended to verbs which are different from the verb "make" because they do not support a direct object?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm afraid this is simply a matter of historical contingency.

In older English you will find *made me to VERB* alongside *made me VERB*, just as in present-day English you find *help me to VERB* alongside *help me VERB*.

Likewise, older English allowed *dared me VERB* and *commanded me VERB* and *compelled me VERB*, where present-day English requires *dared/commanded/compelled me **to** VERB*.

Some require the *to*-marker, others don’t; there’s no general rule.

I believe, however, that where the object does not intervene between the main verb and the complement (as in your examples with the passive), present-day English always requires the *to*-marker.

I cannot offhand think of any exceptions. But I will be happy to retract this answer if anyone comes up with one.

Verbs which “do not support a direct object”—*intransitive* verbs—can’t be cast into the passive, so the ‘rule’ (if indeed it is a rule) does not apply.

Answer (score 1):

[This article](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/infinitive.htm) suggests:

> An infinitive will almost always begin with `to`.
>   Exceptions do occur, however. An infinitive will lose its `to` when it follows certain verbs.
>   These verbs are `feel`, `hear`, `help`, `let`, `make`, `see`, and `watch`.
>   The pattern looks like this: **special verb + direct object + infinitive - to**

When there is no direct object after the special verb, `to` is not omitted. Compare:

> *People were made **to** wait;*
>   *I make **people** wait*;
>   *The boss made **me** work an extra day*;
>   *I was made **to** work an extra day*;
>   *This book helps **to** study*;
>   *I helped **him** study*;
>   *I see **you** run in the mornings*;
>   *You are seen **to** run in the mornings*;